# javascript convert string to safe class name for css

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am sure this must of been asked before but can't find any in the search. 
What is the fastest way to ensure all non safe characters are removed from a string allowing it to be used in a CSS class name?

Comment: Fastest? https://mothereff.in/css-escapes#0~!%40%24%25%5E%26%2a%28%29%5f%2B-%3D%2C.%2F%27%3B%3A%22%3F%3E%3C%5B%5D%5C%7B%7D%7C%60%23

Answer (score 37, accepted):

I would replace anything that is not a lowercase letter or digit, and then I would add a special prefix to avoid collisions with class names you have used for other purposes. For example, here is one possible way:

```
function makeSafeForCSS(name) {
    return name.replace(/[^a-z0-9]/g, function(s) {
        var c = s.charCodeAt(0);
        if (c == 32) return '-';
        if (c >= 65 && c <= 90) return '_' + s.toLowerCase();
        return '__' + ('000' + c.toString(16)).slice(-4);
    });
}

// shows "prefix_c_a_p_s-numb3rs-__0024ymbols"
alert("prefix" + makeSafeForCSS("CAPS numb3rs $ymbols"));
```

Comment: CSS class names cannot begin with a digit. This function does not sanitize class names such as "123class"

Answer (score 14):

If you mean the following symbols

```
!"#$%&'()*+,./:;<=>?@[\]^`{|}~
```

then just replace them with nothing:

```
names = names.replace(/[!\"#$%&'\(\)\*\+,\.\/:;<=>\?\@\[\\\]\^`\{\|\}~]/g, '');
```

(I may have added an extra, or not enough, escape characters in there)

Here is a [quick demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/3j7F7/).

But just so you know, not all of those symbols are "unsafe", you could just escape the symbol when targeting the class name ([ref](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)).

Comment: This won't catch international characters (e.g. à, è, ì, ò, ù, À, È, Ì, Ò, Ù).

Comment: @NexusRex those are all valid to use in class names. In fact, [just about anything is valid](https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/css-escapes) if escaped properly; this now [includes id's in HTML5](https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/html5-id-class). [See also this page](https://mothereff.in/css-escapes).

Comment: Does not catch whitespace. `\s` added to the regex resolves this

Comment: Without extra escapes: ```/[!"#$%&'()*+,./:;<=>?@[\\\]^`{|}~]/g```

Answer (score 4):

I use this for my selectors, IDs or classes names:

```js
String.prototype.safeCSSId = function() {
  return encodeURIComponent(this)
    .toLowerCase()
    .replace(/\.|%[0-9a-z]{2}/gi, '');
}

console.log("The dæmon is in the detail.".safeCSSId());
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try the `urlify.js` from django.

Get it from:
https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/admin/static/admin/js/urlify.js

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is interested in the coffee way of this:

```
window.make_safe_for_css = (name) ->
    name.replace /[^a-z0-9]/g, (s) ->
        c = s.charCodeAt(0)
        if c == 32 then return '-'
        if c >= 65 && c <= 90 then return '_' + s.toLowerCase()
        '__' + '000' + c.toString(16).slice -4
```

Answer (score -1):

with jQuery:

```
$.escapeSelector(stringToEscape);
```

Edit: Misunderstood the original question. This can be used e.g. when querying an element by class name but not for generating the class names.